# Myths on God committing suicide

Tags: native-american, creation, gods, africa, mesoamerica

I am looking for information on myths where God commit suicide, specifically myths based from Central America, South America, and Africa; especially on the idea that earth was created through a God's suicide.
Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Directly from Wikipedia on [Quetzalcoatl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quetzalcoatl), the Aztec winged serpent and creator god:

> In the Codex Chimalpopoca, it is said Quetzalcoatl was coerced by Tezcatlipoca into becoming drunk on pulque, cavorting with his older sister, Quetzalpetlatl, a celibate priestess, and neglecting their religious duties. (Many academics conclude this passage implies incest.) The next morning, Quetzalcoatl, feeling shame and regret, had his servants build him a stone chest, adorn him in turquoise, and then, laying in the chest, **set himself on fire**. His ashes rose into the sky and then his heart followed, becoming the morning star.

Source: [The Death of Quetzalcöätl](https://pages.ucsd.edu/%7Edkjordan/nahuatl/ReadingQuetzalcoatl.html), David K. Jordan
Professor Emeritus of Anthropology, UCSD, website

In Mesoamerican mythology, there is also the legend of the [Fifth Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Suns), where two gods compete in order to decide who has to sacrifice himself in order to save humanity. [Nanahuatzin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanahuatzin) ends up jumping into the bonfire first and becomes the new Sun.

From Sub-Saharan Africa, I found the [creation myth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbombo) of Kuba people in Democratic Republic of the Congo. Mmombo the creator vomited the skies and part of the world, one of his sons, Nyonye Ngana, was supposed to finish the job but died after creating (vomiting) the ants.

Answer (score -1):

Old Sumerian cuneiforms report that the Annunaki said the earth was created from a large chunk of the remains of a larger planet that that was destroyed when it collided with another larger denser planet. Thus, the large planet that bore earth was sacrificed so our earth could be born. In ancient times the planets were given the names of gods and the asteroid belt that was created from the smaller pieces resulting from the collision, was called the golden bracelet.

Comment: This uses too much modern scientific understanding that I doubt Ancient Sumerians would have believe such a story. Got any source?

Comment: If this is the case I would love to see some references to the Tablets and sources